# W3 Total Cache CSS & JS files GZip issues

Tags: htaccess, plugin-w3-total-cache

Having checked my site with google page speed and gzipwtf.com I have noticed that my css and js files are not getting compressed (although html is).

Have tried unchecking " Prevent caching of objects after settings change " and have thus removed query strings from these files but that has had no effect.

Have also tried adding the following (both above and below wordpress rules) in htaccess to no effect also:

```
# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css     application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

Would any one have any advice as to what I may be able to do to rectify this?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like mod_deflate is not present or it is not enabled. You may want to check with your host. HTML compression works, because there are other ways to compress PHP output, rather than using mod_deflate at the server level.

Comment: @pothi I believe it is enabled, I checked using phpinfo and deflate is shown. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pothi Kalimuthu I checked with my hosting company to see if mod_deflate was enabled, and it wasnt. This was the problem.

I mistakingly believed that it was by incorrectly reading the results of phpinfo.